# Spring Data Mongo DB applying @Indexed(unique = true) on nested object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert an object (of `PayLoad`)for each unique `timeStamp` value in `Log` . Annotated `timeStamp` with `@Indexed(unique = true, sparse = true)` and `log` with  `@Valid`.

However , I see duplicates getting inserted. The MongoDB collection used is `PayLoad`.Here's the code snippet.  How do I enforce this unique constrain  ?

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Document(collection = "PayLoad")
public class  PayLoad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1238163054776439285L;
    @Id
    private String payLoadId;
    private String sid;

    @JsonAlias({"results_link"})
    private String resultsLink;
    private  Result result;
}

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SplunkResult implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1698863054778439285L;
    @Id
    String resultId;

    @JsonAlias({"DC"})
    private String dc;
    @JsonAlias({"URL"})
    private String url;
    private String raw;
    private String _raw;
    @Valid
    private List<Log> log;
}

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;

@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Jacksonized
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Log implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5238163054776439285L;

    @Id
    String logId;
    
    @Indexed(unique = true, sparse = true)
    String timeStamp;

    String dc;
    CallStack stk;
}
```

Also tried using `CompoundIndexes` like so , but still it does not work.

```
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(name = "payload_ts_idx", def = "{'result.perfLog.timeStamp' : 1} ",
                unique = true, background = true)})
public class PayLoad implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

the index not be created,try update this config.

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```